# Login to a Windows domain from MacBook Air

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, login, domain

Is it possible to login to a Windows domain from a MacBook Air over WiFi? I can login fine using a wired connected but couldn't using WiFi. WiFi security is 802.1x.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it should be possible.  Your problem may be in the wifi network you are using.  Some companies don't allow people to authenticate to their intranets from the wifi networks they expose, they keep them separated for security.  You have to check with your administrator if the wifi network you are using has access to the domain authenticator.

Comment: You have a valid point. If unauthenticated WiFi users are able to "access" the domain controllers, it's a credible security threat.

Answer (score 0):

First check that you can ping your domain server.  Depending on your router or where you are authenticating to, the wireless network and the wired network aren't on the same subnet. Or in the case of many workplaces, the domain controllers aren't even reachable through the wireless network. . .

Comment: I forgot to mention that to be able to connect to the wireless network, the user needs to feed in his domain credentials via 802.1x